# console window no longer appearing on my Visual Studio Node Console Application

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

The console window appears as expected initially when running the app from Visual Studio but at some point no longer opens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a command from the Package Manager Console from inside Visual Studio it seems to hijack the console window.  Just exit and restart Visual Studio and it should work.

You may have to delete the npm-debug.log as well.

Comment: Still broken over a year later.